# How to sort table with params using jsonp service call back?

Tags: jquery, parameters, jsonp, jquery-callback

How to sort table th heaader with params using jsonp service call back?

url params: adServerId,advertiserId,campaignId,startDate,endDate,active,inactive,sortBy,start,limit

My html code:

```
`<table id="adcampaignGrid" class="grid" onclick="sort()">
<tr>
   <thead>
   <th>Ad Server Id</th>
    <th>Advertiser Id</th>
    <th>Advertiser Name</th>
  <tr>
 </table>`
```

My JQuery code:

```
$.each(data.response.docs, function (i,  item) { // json is the name of the object
        var row = $("<tr></tr>");
        row.append('<td>' + item.adServerId + '</td>'); //item is named at the opening of this $.each function
        row.append('<td>' + item.advertiserId + '</td>');
        row.append('<td>' + item.advertiserName + '</td>');
        row.append('<td>' + item.campaignId + '</td>');
        $("#adcampaignGrid").append(row);
```

Comment: When I click on <th>Ad Server Id</th> it should sort by adServerId param and same thing for other th

Comment: I tried table sorter plugin it was working but it was sorting on client side what table td are on page but I would like to sort from service which has 1000s of records

Comment: i have service but i dont know how to tell service to sort with ajax. Would you please help me? That will be really appreciated.

Comment: How can I pass the column name that I want to sort by into the service call.

Comment: I use service that creates JSONP call back